# Selecting records from column

Tags: mysql, sql, numbers

I have to select **100 highest records** by the number from column.
Structure looks like that:

```
---------
| A | B |
---------
| 1 | 1 |
| 22| 2 |
| 31| 1 |
| 41| 2 |
---------
```

I need  to select for every nr B the highest numbers from column A. In this example it will be

```
---------
| A | B |
---------
| 31| 1 |
| 41| 2 |
---------
```

B1 = 31, 1; B2 = 41, 22.

The task looks quite easy, but I've got more than 10 mln numbers in column A and something like 40 000 nr in column B.

Can you please help me? I'm not really good at sql and script building :(

Comment: I don't understand. Your table has two columns A and B, yes? And you want to show the 100 records with the highest A? Or you want to show the 100 records with the highest A per B (i.e. 40,000 different B x up to 100 records = 4,000,000 result rows)? Or what else? Your sample data is confusing. A and B are columns, yes? Then you should show them as columns (not as rows or separate lists).

Comment: Wich database you are using? I done something like this, but into Mysql, which is possible use subquerey to order by and then group by, which will take the first one of each group.

Comment: Oh, it's with "mysql" tag, you should correct it to MSSQL then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar problem into a project that I made.

You should correct the tag **MySql** to **SQLSERVER**.

I use this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/85d38/1) to make a fiddle about the problem, I think that is what you want.

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
create table tab1 (

  a int,
  b int

);

insert into tab1 (a, b) values 
(1,1),
(22,2),
(11,3),
(31,1),
(10,3),
(41,2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TOP 100 Max(a) as a, b
FROM tab1
GROUP BY b
ORDER BY b asc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/85d38/1/0)**:

```
    |  a | b |
    |----|---|
    | 31 | 1 |
    | 41 | 2 |
    | 11 | 3 |
```

Comment: I'm using Access db. Somebody sad to me that in MySQL it should looks like that:

SELECT b, MAX(a)
FROM tabela
GROUP BY b
ORDER BY b DESC
LIMIT 100

But in access it just dont work. Do you know why?

Comment: I correct the solution from MySQL to MSSQL ;) I hope that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understood, I guess this could help

```
Select Top 10 A , B from tableName group by B , A
```

this will give you the following

```
---------
| A | B |
---------
| 1 | 1 |
| 31| 1 |
| 22| 2 |
| 41| 2 |
---------
```